# Set tag for newly(Runtime) created element

Tags: android, loops, android-linearlayout, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup

I'm creating radio buttons like this in a fragment programmatically in a for loop (i++)

```
for (int i = 1; i < priceList.length(); i++) {
 JSONObject priceObj = (JSONObject) priceList.get(i);
            String catName = priceObj.getString("categoryName");
            String uid = i*(i+100)+20;
            RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            rdbtn.setId((row * 2) + i);
            rdbtn.setText(catName);
            rdbtn.setTextColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
            ll.addView(rdbtn);
}
linearLayout.removeAllViews();
linearLayout.addView(ll);
```

i want to add that uid as tag, but if i add .setTag(uid) it is giving error like below

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                      Process: com.vistaraitsolutions.hoteladmin, PID: 13629
>                                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioButton.setTag(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                          at com.vistaraitsolutions.hoteladmin.FragmentStepThreeBooking.addRadioButtons(FragmentStepThreeBooking.java:226)
>                                                                                          at com.vistaraitsolutions.hoteladmin.FragmentStepThreeBooking$1.onResponse(FragmentStepThreeBooking.java:161)
>                                                                                          at com.vistaraitsolutions.hoteladmin.FragmentStepThreeBooking$1.onResponse(FragmentStepThreeBooking.java:157)
>                                                                                          at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:72)
>                                                                                          at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6856)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

and that tadio buttons not yet added to linear layout yet, aftre loop ony im adding radio group to layout! now i need to set tags.

this is code with setTag()

```
for (int i = 1; i < priceList.length(); i++) {
JSONObject priceObj = (JSONObject) priceList.get(i);
         String catName = priceObj.getString("categoryName");
        String uid = i*(i+100)+20;
        RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        rdbtn.setId((row * 2) + i);
        rdbtn.setText(catName);

        //rdbtn.setTag(url);                here im adding setTag

        rdbtn.setTextColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
        ll.addView(rdbtn);
}
linearLayout.removeAllViews();
linearLayout.addView(ll);
```

please help me

Comment: show where you call the `setTag()` method

Comment: Where do you set a tag? And by the way, having loop in the main thread is not a good idea.

Comment: Can you share the line no 226 in `FragmentStepThreeBooking.java`?

Comment: checkout, i've updated the question with setTag and the line which is having setTag is Line 226

Comment: actually an array is coming from server and i need to loop through that array to show radio buttons.